# How to fix the problem of 'out of memory' in PostGIS Raster processes?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, memory

I am trying to combine a series of overlapping rasters to find out the most recent data.
I think I may have 10,000 layers.
When I run this query:

```
CREATE TABLE most_recent AS
(
    SELECT ST_Union(rast, 'FIRST') most_recent_data,  id
    FROM rasters_table
    GROUP BY id
);
```

I have this error:

```
ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 1081404.
SQL state: 53200
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Increase your pagefile on your server, I am assuming that your PostgreSQL is 64 bit but considering you're trying to run 10k rasters of indeterminate size and CRS you might be asking a bit much, there is no telling how far through the process you're getting before the request for approximately 1 GB fails, you might need to find the most recent in pairs for 9999 iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried different solutions such as partitioning my data and also retiling rasters in smaller tiles. AT the end I found that doing a for loop and processing the raster groups one by one increases the speed dramatically and I do not have the "out of memory" error anymore.

For my purposes I used the following code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS most_recent;

SELECT ST_Union(rast, 'FIRST') most_recent_data, id
INTO most_recent
FROM rasters_table
WHERE id= '1'
GROUP BY id;


DO $$
    DECLARE
    track record;
BEGIN
    FOR track IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM rasters_table) LOOP

        INSERT INTO most_recent
        SELECT ST_Union(rast, 'FIRST') most_recent_data,  id
        FROM rasters_table
        WHERE id = track.id
        GROUP BY id;
    
    END LOOP;
END $$ ;
```

In fact, the only thing that this code does is:
doing the process once for each id instead of loading all at the same time in the memory (or probably hard drive) and then processign it.
Before it used to take 24 hours and then break but now it took only 24 minutes and 30 sec. I cannot believe!!

Comment: That is the life in GIS world, sometimes just slight adjustment of process / code / SQL can make things 1000 times faster, like spatial indexes for vector data :)

Comment: I had some other processes that I rewrote them with for loop and the same technique. It is unbelievable how fast it is !!  I really suggest for loops :D